# Valid false values

Tags: javascript, boolean

Converting any value to `Boolean` returns `false` or `true`. For example:

```
> Boolean (false)
false
> Boolean (null)
false
> Boolean (undefined)
false
> Boolean ("")
false
```

But `0` is special, because it's a number. I consider is as a valid false value:

```
> Boolean (0)
false
```

Are there any other *valid* false values?

Comment: Could you define "valid"?

Comment: @Aioros thefourtheye already gave a good answer. :-) Imagine that we have a field called `myField` that is *required*. So, I need to validate its value. It cannot be `false`, `undefined` etc but can be `0` - for example.

Comment: @IonicăBizău In general, test the conditions you actually care about. e.g. if it must be a number use `typeof myField === "number"`, rather than `!myField`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g In my case `myField` can be any *valid* value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per [ECMA 5.1 Standards](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2), Truthiness of an expression will be decided, as per the following table

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Argument Type | Result                                                |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Undefined     | false                                                 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Null          | false                                                 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion). |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Number        | The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN;|
|               | otherwise the result is true.                         |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| String        | The result is false if the argument is the empty      |
|               | String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is  |
|               | true.                                                 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Object        | true                                                  |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, you have missed `-0` and `NaN`.

```
console.log(Boolean(-0));
# false
console.log(Boolean(NaN));
# false
```