# Differences between 0, -0 and +0

Tags: javascript

I never understood why `-0` treated separately than `0`.

The interesting fact is that `0` is equal with `-0`

```
> 0 === -0
true
```

Then, the question is: why is `-0` [treated separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368135/1420197) than `0` and `+0`?

Is there any case when the sign before `0` matters?

In mathematics `+0` is a value just a little greater than `0`. Also, `-0` is a value just a little lower than `0`. For example: `n / Infinity` would return `+0` and `n / -Infinity` `-0` (supposing that `n` is a real number greater than 0). This happens in mathematics.

Comment: I think the answer may be, because that's how the language says it should be treated.

Comment: It is defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754. The simple reason is that in binary representation in memory there is one bit defining the sign of the number. Simply by this fact it is possible for all represented numbers to be positive or negative (combinatorially).

Comment: May be this Question and its answer give some idea [How do I check if a zero is positive or negative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409102/how-do-i-check-if-a-zero-is-positive-or-negative) Not sure but ;)

Comment: I may be wrong but doesn't `-0` and `+0` parse it to a number? So it's basically the equivalent of `Number(-0)` and `Number(0)`?

Comment: If you add a arithmetic operator to any type in javascript it becomes a number. So if you add it to a number it stays a number.

Comment: To begin with there are not 3 zero : just two : +0 and -0.

Comment: it's essentially down to the fact that the binary 1000...0000 is the same as 0000...0000 if you're using signed integers (i.e one bit is used to show the sign)

Comment: @talemyn Also of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7223717/1420197

Comment: @GameAlchemist I agree. Just 2 votes more are needed. :-) Anyway, some interesting answers I found. Thank you!

Comment: If you really agree, then delete ! ;-) ;-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist *close* is not *delete*. Even a question is duplicate it doesn't mean that it should be deleted. More questions (even duplicated) helps Google to give you better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit "](http://people.freebsd.org/%7Edas/kahan86branch.pdf) addresses the reasons for signed zeros.  That kind of analysis informed IEEE-754 which is the basis for most modern instruction sets
and programming languages' floating point number behavior.

In brief, many common numeric functions can be continuous with signed zeroes at places where they cannot be with an unsigned zero leading to fewer `NaN` values and fewer special cases.  Division is one such function.

---

> Then, the question is: why is -0 treated separately than 0 and +0?

Just to be clear, there are only two zero values.  -0 and +0.  The tokens `(0)` can be substituted for the tokens `(+0)` wherever they occur without changing semantics.

---

> The interesting fact is that 0 is equal with -0
>
> ```
> 0 === -0
> true
> ```

This behavior is mandated by IEEE-754.

To test whether two numeric values are the "same":

```
function same(x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    if (x !== 0) {
      return true;  // Non-zero values.
    } else {
      return (1/x === 1/y);  // Test signed-ness of zeroes.
    }
  } else {
    return x !== x && y !== y;  // Treat NaNs the same
  }
}
```