# Why does !!1=="1" equal true and !!2=="2" equal false?

Tags: javascript

As the title states, why does:

```
> !!1=="1"
```

equal

```
True
```

and

```
> !!2=="2"
```

equal:

```
False
```

Likewise, why does `> "1"==true` equal `true` and `> "2"==true` equal `false`

I'm baffled. Are these just bugs in JS or what's going on here?

Comment: @Michael: 2==“2” equal false for you? For me it's working correctly http://jsfiddle.net/HGEcs/

Comment: This is why you should ALWAYS be using `===` for comparison in JavaScript.

Comment: Is the javascript bang like the C bang?  If so, then `!!1` and `!!2` both equal 1.

Comment: yes its a "bug" and highly discouraged. it is very confusing. == does type coercion see http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types for more details. and read Javscript: The Good Parts book

Comment: No, it's not a bug. You simply should not compare booleans to strings if you don't know what it means.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "bug".  In the usual sense of the word, no, this isn't a bug - but it *is* a design flaw.

Comment: You could have easily figured that out by yourself by adding parantheses to figure out which operator takes precedence.

Comment: Please notice that these aren't duplicates. We here are considering the case **compare boolean to numeric string**, not something similar.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'd say it's not a design _flaw_ but an example of a design convenience (being able to use `123=="123"`) that can be misused, either by design or accident.

Comment: @Bergi you marked this as a duplicate, why? It's not the same question. This question is much more clear and what would be searched if someone were looking for the answer.

Comment: @MichaelRader: No, I did not (see my previous comment about why it's not a dupe). In fact, [I just reopened it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23693089/revisions) with my Gold Badge priviledges :-)

Comment: @Bergi great, I appreciate it. I Google this exact questions with no answers found, so i think it will be searched similarly by others.

Comment: Though I'm very much of the opinion that weak dynamic type systems are a bad idea, I don't know what you find so strange about this particular example. You also wouldn't be surprised to see that `1 * 1 == 1` yet `2 * 2 ≠ 2`, would you? You have in mind that `!` should be self-inverse and hence `!!` never do anything, but this is obviosly only true if you restrict yourself to proper boolean values (which is a no-brainer in a proper strong static type system).

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand why this question keeps getting closed. Can you reopen it again??

Answer (score 207, accepted):

As per the [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) rules, logical `!` has higher priority over `==`. So, in both the cases, `!!` is evaluated first.

**Note:** Truthiness of various objects have been explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368135/1903116) of mine.

#### First Case

```
!!1 == "1"
```

`!1` will be evaluated to `false`, since `1` is considered Truthy. Negating again we get `true`. So the expression becomes

```
true == "1"
```

Now, the coercion rules kick in as you have used `==` operator, which evaluates as per the [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) defined in ECMAScript 5.1 Specification,

> 6. If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

So, `true` will be converted to a number, which is 1 as per [`ToNumber` algorithm for Boolean values](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3). Now the expression becomes

```
1 == "1"
```

Now,

> 4. If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`,
>         return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

So, `"1"` will be converted to a number and that will give 1, as per the [`ToNumber` algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3.1). That is why it shows `true` in the first case.

#### Second Case

The same rules are applied here.

```
!!2 == "2"
```

becomes

```
true == "2"
```

then

```
1 == "2"
```

which becomes

```
1 == 2
```

which is not `true`, that is why the second case prints `false`.

Comment: +1 No wonder: `100==true` is always false. This lingered some Confusion as in; How can both `Negative Numbers` and `Positive Number` `== true` be `false` except 1 which is a Positive number?... Your Explanation really shades some GreatLight on this issue. mostly the point **4.**

Comment: @MichaelRader Nope :-) It is the intended behavior, as per the specifications.

Comment: @MichaelRader If you want to compare the values then you might want to use `===` operator, which uses [Strict Equality Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)

Comment: It uses this Logic: **Number:** *The result is false if the argument is* `+0`, `−0`, or `NaN;` otherwise the result is `true`. See: http://es5.github.io/#x9.2

Comment: @thefourtheye very interesting, considering the book I'm going through calls them "bugs rather than features." Had a feeling there had to be some logic behind it. And yes, I would always use `===`.

Comment: @MichaelRader Sure, but please go through the documentation to know the limitations of `===` before diving in ;-)

Comment: @ErickBest You are correct, any other number is considered Truthy :)

Comment: I'm not new, lol, I know the limitations. I'm just trying to get a better grasp of the inner workings.

Comment: I love when people give step-by-step breakdowns of code, because not all of us know what goes on in the background. Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to create a statement out of this, you might opt for a little boolean algebra, so if you have `var1 = 2` and `var2 = 2`, then you can use `if !!var1 and var2`, since you're not checking for the integer value of these numbers, but instead want their boolean value.

Comment: Better use `===` for value comparison and I do love the answer `Yes, this is javascript`

Answer (score 13):

tldr; this is due to the [[ToNumber]](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) conversions in the `==` operator algorithm.

The first step is to simplify the expression. Since `!!x=="x"` is parsed like `(!!x)=="x"` and `!!a_truthy_expression -> true`, the actual relevant expression for the equality is

```
!!1=="2" -> true=="1" -> Boolean==String
!!2=="2" -> true=="2" -> Boolean==String
```

So then looking at the rules for [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) and following along with the application yields

> Rule 6 - If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

which results in `Number==String` or 1=="1" and 1=="2", respectively<sup>1</sup>. Then the rule

> Rule 7 - If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
>   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

is applied which results in `Number==Number` or 1==1 and 1==2, respectively<sup>1</sup>; the latter is clearly false.

> Rule 1 - If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then [by c.iii.] If x is the same Number value as y, return true [else return false].

(The same algorithm explains the `String==Boolean` case when the complementing rules are applied.)

---

<sup>1</sup>To see the [ToNumber] rule applied, consider:

```
+false -> 0
+true  -> 1
+"1"   -> 1
+"2"   -> 2
```

Answer (score 5):

**Its a precedence operator problem.**

The `!` operator is an unary operator. That means the left side must be an expression or a boolean evaluable section. See [Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

```
!!1==1 is not necessary !!(1==1)
!!2==2 is not necessary !!(2==2)
```

I think that these expressions should be consistent if the equal operator has more precedence than ! operator. But if we consider the opposite, evaluating first negations we have:

```
!!1 == 1
!1 -> false
!!1 -> true
!!1 == 1
```

And with the two

```
!!2==2
!2 -> false
!!2 -> true
(!!2) == 2 -> false
```

That is because the ! operator has precedence over == operator

See [Mozilla Operator Preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 1):

`!!1` is equal to true, and "1" is equal to true ("0" is false, so is every other string). So `!!1 == "1"` evaluates to `true == true`, which of course returns true.

`!!2` is also equal to true. As I mentioned earlier, "2" is not "1", so it's false. Therefore,  we have `true == false`, which of course returns false.

If you want to see if 2 (a number) is equal to "2" (a string representation of a number), then all you have to do is `2 == "2"`, which evaluates to `2 == 2`, which is true. The difference is that we're not comparing a boolean against a boolean. We're comparing a number against a number.

Basically, putting `!!` in front of a number converts to a boolean, which forces JavaScript to cast your string to a boolean instead of a number.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said.

Comment: YOU SAID: *As I mentioned earlier, "2" is not "1".* Did he say `2 == 1` ??... try to explain that point

Comment: I said that "1" is the only string that is equal to true. Therefore, "2" is equal to false, which gives the expression `true == false`, hence why `!!2 == "2"` is false.

Comment: -1. The strings are not being casted to booleans. The booleans are casted to numbers. Also, "*"0" is false*" is confusing (if not wrong), because `"0"` is truthy: `!!"0" === true` and `"0" == false`

Comment: -1. `!!"" === false`, `!!anyOtherString === true`. In other words the empty string is falsey, all other strings are truthy.  Your first sentence directly contradicts this

Answer (score -1):

Because "1" may be considered as "true" when you do equality check, not identity, but "2" - can't.

Comment: Consider `!!2` vs `!!1` - both evaluate to `true` (as such, both 1 and 2 are truthy-values)