# How to understand this example of a logical and ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I understand that ternary operators are essentially a shortcut for an `if-else` statement, and I also understand that `&&` is a logical AND. However, I don't understand how the two are combined in the code below.

I tried playing around with the output as well, but it didn't help. How do I interpret the following?

```
function greetUser(customerName, sex)  {
  var salutation  = sex && sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";
  console.log("Hello, " + salutation + " " + customerName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the ternary operator means:

```
condition ? (value returned if condition is true) : (value returned if condition is false)
```

In your example, the condition is `sex && sex === 'Man'`, which means that the value contained in the variable `sex` is **[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [strictly equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)** to the string `"Man"`.

Here's the breakdown:

```
var salutation;
if(sex && sex === 'Man') {  
    salutation = 'Mr';
} else {
    salutation = 'Ms';
}
```

Furthermore, in this particular example, since you are using **strict equality** (i.e. `===`) comparison, there isn't any point to the truthfulness check for `sex`, it is unnecessary. Your condition can just be:

```
var salutation = sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";
```

*Explanation*: When using `&&`, both operands are coerced to booleans first so their "truthfulness" can be AND-ed. For example, let's say `sex = 'Man'`, then your condition would essentially be:

```
if('Man' && 'Man' === 'Man')
```

Which coerced to booleans is:

```
if(true && true)
```

Which is clearly redundant. [Read more about JavaScript type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript).

This truthy check is a good safety check in other situations that happen when using a non-strict comparison operator such as `==`, `<`, `>` ... instead of `===`.

In simple terms, using `==` first coerces both items to the same type before comparing which can [lead to bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693089/why-does-1-1-equal-true-and-2-2-equal-false). Using `===` immediately returns `false` if the types differ, hence it is safer.

Here's a [another useful resource](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) for JavaScript comparisons.

Comment: But why is the first `sex` needed at all? Why not just have the ternary operator? I don't see what purpose the first `sex` provides.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is a logical `and` defined as,

```
(true && true) == true
(true && false) == false
(false && true) == false
(false && false) == false
```

So, a statement `A && B` is only true if both A and B are true

In your case, with the ternary operator, some brackets might help so you can see in which order these operators are evaluated.

```
(sex && (sex === "Man")) ? "Mr." : "Ms."
```

So, in English...

if `sex` exists AND `sex` is `'Man'` then `"Mr."` else `"Ms."`

In general the ternary operator works like this:

```
(true OR false) ? (value if true) : (value if false)
```

Comment: So the first `sex` is just to check if the argument is nonempty? Why not `!sex` instead then?

Answer (score 1):

is sex is not undefined and sex is `Man` then `Mr.` ; else `Ms.`. So in case sex is undefined; it will be `Ms.` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line

```
var salutation  = sex && sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";
```

to

```
var salutation  = ((sex) && (sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms."));
```

Now `sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms."` tells you that if the value of sex variable is `Man` and the type of both the variables is same(that is String in this case), then it should return `Mr` else `Ms`.