# Best way to check undefined element in an array

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have an array linking integers to objects:

```
var array = [];
array[3] = new Something();
array[42] = new OtherSomething();
array[84] = new SomethingAgain();
```

I want to check if an field exists in an array, and then use it if it does.

```
var field = array[row];
```

If the array doesn't contain any field with index `row`, then `field` will be set to `undefined`.

My question is: what is the best way to check its existence between:

```
if (field !== undefined) { /* Do stuff with field */ }
```

And:

```
if (field) { /* Do stuff with field */ }
```

The second solution is shorter, so it could be quicker to execute, because JavaScript is an interpreted scripting language. But in another hand, it might check for boolean value of `field`, or something like that...

What is your point on this ?

Comment: What is `row` and how the `array` is defined? Is it a 2-D Array?

Comment: @thefourtheye `row` is an integer and array is a simple array filled with objects. I added a definition exemple.

Comment: Why you are not using objects?

Comment: If you are looking for performance, you should just try it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" is a fairly subjective term, so let's throw some objective criteria at it:

1. Which is faster?

   In a way that you'll **notice** in the **real world**, neither. But if you really want to know, [measure your specific code](http://jsperf.com) on the engines you want to support.
2. Which is easier to read?

   This is probably subjective as well. The second form is **extremely** common in JavaScript, FWIW.
3. Which is less typing?

   The second form is obviously a lot shorter than the first.
4. Which is more reliable?

   Given your use case, they're equally reliable, because you're either not storing an entry in the array at all, or storing a non-`null` object reference.

   In similar but different use cases, you might need to be wary of the difference: The first form will **only** be true for an entry that exists and doesn't have the value `undefined` in it. The second form will be true for anything that isn't *falsey*. There are several falsey values: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. So you wouldn't use the second form to decide whether there was a number at a position in the array, since `0` is a number but `if (0)` won't go into the body of the `if`.

   Speaking of ambiguity, note that comment about "...true for an entry that exists and doesn't have the value `undefined` in it..." Neither of the examples you gave differentiates between an entry that *doesn't exist* and an entry that exists with the value `undefined`. If you need to differentiate those at some point (again, not for the use case you mentioned), you'd use `hasOwnProperty` on the array: `if (array.hasOwnProperty(row))`

> The second solution is shorter, so it could be quicker to execute, because JavaScript is an interpreted scripting language

This is a mistaken assumption. Most modern JavaScript engines are just-in-time optimizing compilers. V8 (the engine in Chrome), for instance, is a *two-stage* optimizing compiler: On the first pass, it turns your JavaScript into machine code quickly, and then if it identifies hotspots (bits of code that run a lot), it goes back and does more aggressive optimization there.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, thanks. That was my first thought looking at the question, not quite sure how I forgot to actually include it in the answer!

Answer (score 4):

The array what you created is called a *sparse array*. You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448440/1903116).

The check

```
if (field !== undefined)
```

might not help if the actual value stored in the array itself is `undefined`. And this check

```
if (field)
```

will evaluate to be truthy if `field` is any one of the Truthy values. You can read more about the Truthiness and Falsiness of different values in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368135/1903116).

So, if you want to know if the array has a particular index, then you can use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), like this

```
var array = [];
array[1] = undefined;

console.log(array[0]);
// undefined
console.log(array[1]);
// undefined
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(0));
// false
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(1));
// true
```

Here the element at `1` is defined to be `undefined`, but since `0` is not defined at all, by default, JavaScript returns `undefined`.

The `hasOwnProperty` call checks if the current object really has the index `0` and `1`.

Comment: Well, if he expects to have objects stored in the array, then `if (arr[i])` is totally fine.

Comment: @Bergi True, but I feel that OP wants to know if the key (index) exists in the array.

Comment: @Bergi right, I will never stock `undefined` in an array. So may I understand in my case, `if (field)` is the simpliest one ?

Comment: @Aracthor If you will not store any other falsy values, then yes, you can go with `if (field)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you this example. Hope it helps you feel clearer.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = undefined;
arr[2] = null;
arr[3] = NaN;
arr[4] = '';
arr[5] = false;

arr[11] = 1;
arr[12] = [];
arr[13] = {};
arr[14] = 'hello';  
arr[15] = true;  

if(arr[0]) //false but exists
if(arr[1]) //false but exists
if(arr[2]) //false but exists
if(arr[3]) //false but exists
if(arr[4]) //false but exists
if(arr[5]) //false but exists

if(arr[6]) //false and not exist
if(arr[7]) //false and not exist
if(arr[8]) //false and not exist
if(arr[9]) //false and not exist
if(arr[10]) //false and not exist  

if(arr[11]) //true and exists
if(arr[12]) //true and exists
if(arr[13]) //true and exists
if(arr[14]) //true and exists
if(arr[15]) //true and exists
```

In general, I recommend you to use the second solution for checking existence since it's shorter and easier to read. However, it still strongly depends on your case. Make sure that your choice is not going to fail in any unexpected situations.